# read xml node's attribute using php

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

i am trying to read xml node's attribute from that file
using simple xml reader

```
<songs>
<song title="On Mercury" artist="Red Hot Chili Peppers" path="/red-hot-chili-peppers/on-mercury.mp3" />
<song title="Universally Speaking" artist="Red Hot Chili Peppers" path="/red-hot-chili-peppers/universally-speaking.mp3" />
</songs>
```

i used that code to read it
but it gave me xml parse error

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("playlist.xml") 
       or die("Error: Cannot create object");

foreach($xml->children() as $data){
      echo $data->song['title'];
      echo "<br />";

}

?>
```

please help me

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call both `->children()` and `->song`. The first gives you all children of a particular node regardless of tag name, the second gives you all children of a particular node with the tag name "song".

Try:

```
foreach($xml->song as $song){
    echo $song['title'];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
foreach($xml->children() as $data) {
    if ( $data->getName() == 'song' ) {
        echo $data['title'];
        echo "<br />";
    }
}
```